# Kinvey endpoint not working

Tags: javascript, endpoint, business-logic, kinvey

I have this endpoint

```
function onRequest(request, response, modules) {
    modules.logger.info(request.body.de);
    response.complete(200);
}
```

and I'm trying to execute in my javascript like this:

```
 var promise = Kinvey.execute('myendpoint', {
       de: "test"
    }, { 
       success: function(response) {
          console.log("it works!");
       }
    });
```

I followed the tutorial on Kinvey. I already test the code on the Kinvey console with no problems. (Already tried with `Kinvey.execute(':myendpoint)...` in case somebody thinks that is the problem).

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is your console output.

Comment: Sorry guys. I forgot to include the Kinvey init. Thanks anyway!

Comment: May I ask what version of the kinvey package you are using?  I'm having the same issue (however I am initializing Kinvey just fine).  Thanks.